# Trying to use Distributed data parallel on GANs but getting runtime error about an inplace operation

Tags: neural-network, multiprocessing, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, multi-gpu

I am trying to train a GAN a machine with 3GPUs using distributed data parallel.
before wrapping my model in the DDP everything works fine but when I wrap it, it givers me the following Runtime Error

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [128]] is at version 5; expected version 4 instead.

I cloned every related tensor to the gradient to solve the inplace operation (if it is any) but I could not find it.

the part of code with the problem is as follow:

```
Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor


# ----------
#  Training
# ----------

def train_gan(rank, world_size, opt):
    print(f"Running basic DDP example on rank {rank}.")
    setup(rank, world_size)

    if rank == 0:
        get_dataloader(rank, opt)
    dist.barrier()
    print(f"Rank {rank}/{world_size} training process passed data download barrier.\n")

    dataloader = get_dataloader(rank, opt)

    # Loss function
    adversarial_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()
    # Initialize generator and discriminator
    generator = Generator()
    discriminator = Discriminator()
    # Initialize weights
    generator.apply(weights_init_normal)
    discriminator.apply(weights_init_normal)

    generator.to(rank)
    discriminator.to(rank)

    generator_d = DDP(generator, device_ids=[rank])
    discriminator_d = DDP(discriminator, device_ids=[rank])


    # Optimizers
    # Since we are computing the average of several batches at once (an effective batch size of
    # world_size * batch_size) we scale the learning rate to match.
    optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(generator_d.parameters(), lr=opt.lr * opt.world_size, betas=(opt.b1, opt.b2))
    optimizer_D = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator_d.parameters(), lr=opt.lr * opt.world_size, betas=(opt.b1, opt.b2))

    losses = []

    for epoch in range(opt.n_epochs):
        for i, (imgs, _) in enumerate(dataloader):

            # Adversarial ground truths
            valid = Variable(Tensor(imgs.shape[0], 1).fill_(1.0), requires_grad=False).to(rank)
            fake = Variable(Tensor(imgs.shape[0], 1).fill_(0.0), requires_grad=False).to(rank)

            # Configure input
            real_imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor)).to(rank)

            # -----------------
            #  Train Generator
            # -----------------

            optimizer_G.zero_grad()

            # Sample noise as generator input
            z = Variable(Tensor(np.random.normal(0, 1, (imgs.shape[0], opt.latent_dim)))).to(rank)

            # Generate a batch of images
            gen_imgs = generator_d(z)

            # Loss measures generator's ability to fool the discriminator
            g_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator_d(gen_imgs), valid)

            g_loss.backward()
            optimizer_G.step()

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            optimizer_D.zero_grad()

            # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
            real_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator_d(real_imgs), valid)
            fake_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator_d(gen_imgs.detach()), fake)
            d_loss = ((real_loss + fake_loss) / 2).to(rank)

            

            d_loss.backward()
            optimizer_D.step()
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error when trying to train a GAN with `DistributedDataParallel`.
I noticed the problem was coming from `BatchNorm` layers in my discriminator.

Indeed, `DistributedDataParallel` synchronizes the batchnorm parameters at each forward pass ([see the doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/ddp.html)), thereby modifying the variable inplace, which causes problems if you have multiple forward passes in a row.

Converting my `BatchNorm` layers to [`SyncBatchNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.SyncBatchNorm.html) did the trick for me:

```py
discriminator = torch.nn.SyncBatchNorm.convert_sync_batchnorm(discriminator)
discriminator = DPP(discriminator)
```

You probably want to do it anyway when using `DistributedDataParallel`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `SyncBatchNorm`, you can set the `broadcast_buffers` parameter to `False`, but I don't think you really want to do that, as it means your batch norm stats will not be synchronized among processes.

```py
discriminator = DPP(discriminator, device_ids=[rank], broadcast_buffers=False)
```